Can't assign array from JSON to a new variable and return in reponse in Azure Logic App
I am trying to create my first Logic app to filter a query from a third party API service.
The third party API responds with both a SearchSummary (Object) and Data (Array) items.
I want to return only the Data array in my response, but keep getting an error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NoResponse",
        "message": "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id '08584773567277623430271089584CU00'."
    }
}

If I change the variable assignment from @body('Parse_JSON')?['Data'] to @body('Parse_JSON')?['SearchSummary'] then the SearchSummary returns fine. I've tried appending .items to the value but that also doesn't help.
When I return length(@body('Parse_JSON')?['Data']) in my response, it does return an accurate number so there are definitely items there.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the code view from my app:
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_Contacts_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "OnlineContacts",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Data']"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "ApiToken": "XXX"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://api.companysearch.com/v1/data?query=X+Y+Z"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            },
                        "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('HTTP')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Data": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "MEMBERSHIP_DATA": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "companyId": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "companyName": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "dept": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "endDate": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "startDate": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "status": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "title": {
                                                        "type": [
                                                            "string",
                                                            "null"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "birthdate": {
                                            "type": [
                                                "string",
                                                "null"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "dirId": {
                                            "type": [
                                                "string",
                                                "null"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "firstName": {
                                            "type": [
                                                "string",
                                                "null"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "lastName": {
                                            "type": [
                                                "string",
                                                "null"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "middleName": {
                                            "type": [
                                                "string",
                                                "null"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            },
                            "SearchSummary": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "DatabaseInfo": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "IndexationDate": {},
                                            "ReleaseNumber": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "UpdateDate": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "UpdateNumber": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "VersionNumber": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "Offset": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "RecordsReturned": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "Sort": {},
                                    "TotalRecordsFound": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "HTTP": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@variables('OnlineContacts')",
                    "statusCode": "@outputs('HTTP')?['statusCode']"
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_Contacts_Array": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateless"
}

Here is a sample JSON payload that the HTTP request retrieves:
{
    "SearchSummary": {
        "TotalRecordsFound": 48,
        "Offset": 0,
        "RecordsReturned": 48,
        "DatabaseInfo": {
            "ReleaseNumber": "43",
            "UpdateNumber": "431",
            "UpdateDate": "2024-08-20T00:00:00",
            "VersionNumber": "129.00",
            "IndexationDate": null
        },
        "Sort": null
    },
    "Data": [
        {
            "birthdate": "1950-06-01T00:00:00",
            "firstName": "Ian",
            "middleName": "Charlie",
            "lastName": "Jones",
            "dirId": "P003577888",
            "MEMBERSHIP_DATA": [
                {
                    "companyId": null,
                    "companyName": null,
                    "startDate": null,
                    "status": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "title": null,
                    "dept": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "birthdate": "1919-05-11T00:00:00",
            "firstName": "Dorothy",
            "middleName": "June",
            "lastName": "Perkins",
            "dirId": "P003890700",
            "MEMBERSHIP_DATA": [
                {
                    "companyId": null,
                    "companyName": null,
                    "startDate": null,
                    "status": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "title": null,
                    "dept": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "birthdate": "1947-11-09T00:00:00",
            "firstName": "Paul",
            "middleName": "Dean",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "dirId": "P003890600",
            "MEMBERSHIP_DATA": [
                {
                    "companyId": "GB04969800",
                    "companyName": "Acme Ltd 1",
                    "startDate": "2020-04-15T00:00:00",
                    "status": "Current",
                    "endDate": null,
                    "title": "Director",
                    "dept": "Board of Directors; Senior management"
                },
                {
                    "companyId": "GB07346800",
                    "companyName": "Acme Ltd 2",
                    "startDate": "2010-08-16T00:00:00",
                    "status": "Current",
                    "endDate": null,
                    "title": "Director",
                    "dept": "Board of Directors; Senior management"
                },
                {
                    "companyId": "GB06741800",
                    "companyName": "Acme Ltd 3",
                    "startDate": "2008-11-04T00:00:00",
                    "status": "Current",
                    "endDate": null,
                    "title": "Director",
                    "dept": "Board of Directors; Senior management"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}



I tested your workflow, and it returns the Data array as expected, no error.

@10p I have updated my original post, it appears whenever there is more than 2 items in the MEMBERSHIP_DATA it appears to fail. When I remove the first or the last item from Ian Jones's MEMBERSHIP_DATA it appears to work fine.

Thank you for updating your question with the correct data needed to reproduce the issue. The content of your variable exceeded 1024 bytes - refer to the link in my answer below.

You have to use stateful, and  then only it will work.

Your workflow fails because it is stateless, not stateful, and the content size of your variable OnlineContacts exceeds the maximum allowed size of 1024 bytes. Please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings#variables to update the maximum configured value.
Alternatively, you can try using a Compose action instead of the variable in your stateless workflow, if your scenario allows it. This constructs a single output and avoids the limitations associated with variable content.

Is it still possible to make this a syncronouse callout while also making it stateful?

@InvalidSyntax, of course it is possible. You can try copying your workflow code to a new workflow, only instead of "kind": "Stateless" at the end of the JSON use "kind": "Stateful". You can also try using the Compose action instead of the variable in your stateless workflow, if your scenario allows it.

This appear to make the app now work, however it takes a while to process now (sometimes 2-3x the execution time). Is there a reason for this? and how could I make it faster? I'm conscious I haven't even added all my other business logic so it will likely even go slower.

@InvalidSyntax, stateless workflows generally take less time to complete because they run entirely in memory and  do not use external storage. This eliminates the latency associated with state persistence. If using stateless workflows is essential to your business needs, you can adjust the Runtime.Backend.VariableOperation.MaximumStatelessVariableSize setting. Alternatively, you can test using the Compose action instead of the OnlineContacts variable.

How does the Compose action differ to using a variable?

@InvalidSyntax, A variable can be set to different values multiple times during a workflow. However, if you only need to initialize a variable once and don’t plan to change its value, you can use a Compose action instead. This constructs a single output and avoids the limitations associated with variable content.


Can't assign array from JSON to a new variable and return in reponse in Azure Logic App

It works fine for me using below design even with 3 membership data:

In Compose stored your given sample data with 3 MEMBERSHIP_DATA . And my Parse_Json schema is:
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "SearchSummary": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "TotalRecordsFound": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "Offset": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "RecordsReturned": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "DatabaseInfo": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "ReleaseNumber": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "UpdateNumber": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "UpdateDate": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "VersionNumber": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "IndexationDate": {}
                    }
                },
                "Sort": {}
            }
        },
        "Data": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "birthdate": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "firstName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "middleName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "lastName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "dirId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "MEMBERSHIP_DATA": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "companyId": {},
                                "companyName": {},
                                "startDate": {},
                                "status": {},
                                "endDate": {},
                                "title": {},
                                "dept": {}
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "companyId",
                                "companyName",
                                "startDate",
                                "status",
                                "endDate",
                                "title",
                                "dept"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "birthdate",
                    "firstName",
                    "middleName",
                    "lastName",
                    "dirId",
                    "MEMBERSHIP_DATA"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

Make sure you use above Schema as it worked for me.
Output:

